# Why can't my LAN connect to OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn

Goal:

Setup a secure connection between remote user and LAN servers via OpenVPN.

Purpose:

I am starting a business where an artist will require access to server-farm. We have tested connection directly from farm to artist; however anyone can access this service via it's public IP and port. We need to keep these computers behind OpenVPN on a LAN only accessible after proper authentication.

Here is the current network scheme:

```
76.213.x.x public IP via enp6s0 on OpenVPN box
10.8.0.1 tun0 on OpenVPN
192.168.2.1 enp3s0 on OpenVPN box
192.168.2.2 Network Adapter 1 on Windows Client 1
192.168.2.3 Network Adapter 1 on Windows Client 2 via enp6s0 on OpenVPN
```

Steps taken so far:

Installed OpenVPN on linux server, issued all necessary keys, transferred key to artist's rig, installed Openvpn client, and connected successfully to OpenVPN.

We can ping both NICs on the OpenVPN server, and the TUN virtual interface.

On the other end, with the windows rigs we have disabled firewall and pinged computers connected to the LAN.

The issue is pinging from windows rigs on LAN to OpenVPN (and by extension artist). Or the other way around Pinging from (artist -> ) OpenVPN to windows rigs on LAN.

I have the following setup for server.conf on OpenVPN:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

My iptables rules are:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o enp3s0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 192.168.2.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o enp6s0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i enp3s0 -o enp6s0 -s 192.168.2.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

& I issue the following command:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Without success so far. It would appear a tweak is necessary in my firewall rules, but I can't figure this out. Perhaps something else is at play?

UPDATE

As requested in comment, here is the routing tables

WC1 LAN:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.2.2    266
      192.168.2.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.2    266
    192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.2    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.2.2    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.2    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Artists Rig:

```
 IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254     192.168.1.65     25
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.8.0.4    276
         10.8.0.4  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.4    276
       10.8.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.4    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.65    281
     192.168.1.65  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.65    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.65    281
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.4     20
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.8.0.4    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.65    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.4    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.65    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: I wouldn't use NAT here, since you can just set up normal IP routing between `192.168.2.0/24` and `10.8.0.0/24` networks. What does the routing table look at the Windows rigs and the artist's routing table? What is the artist's environment?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Hi I've added the routing table of a Windows rig and the Artists rig. His environment is Windows 10. Please let me know if you need more information, and thanks for trying to help out. I will take out the two NAT rules now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WC1 LAN has no default route. So it should at least have route to the OpenVPN network:

```
route add 10.8.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.1
```

This is because the artist's rig has IP address on the `10.8.0.0/24` network, and WC1 has no route to that IP address.

Artist's rig routing table looks correct, there is the route to `192.168.2.0/24` network via OpenVPN gateway `10.8.0.1`.

Comment: This is the correct route. I had previously tried adding this one among many others. The real issue was a faulty NIC. Never had that happen before. I replaced it with a spare identical, added the route, and was setup spiffy!